# run regex on file object instead of string

Tags: python, regex, parsing, etl

I wrote a nice little sql to csv expression (below) that works on the format of the mysqldump data that I would like to process.

However, I would like to walk this over **very large** files, possibly too large to fit in memory. The input may be [gb]zipped and does not contain line breaks. Ideally I would like to be able to process the input data as it is read in from a network location rather than downloading it first and then reading the file off disk.

How can I run a regex on a file-like object or using chunked reads?

```
def sql2csv(buf):
  rowmatcher = re.compile(r"""
    (?<=\()
      (?:
        (?:
          -?\d+(?:\.\d+)?
          |NULL
          |'(?:[^'\\]|\\')*'
        )
        (?:,|(?=\)))
      )+
    (?=\)[,;])
    """, re.X)

  return (
      [r.decode('string_escape').decode('utf8') for r in row]
      for row in csv.reader(
          (x.group(0) for x in rowmatcher.finditer(buf)),
          quotechar="'", escapechar='\\', doublequote=False))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this maybe?

```
#pseudocode

buf = read(1024)
while True:
   if re.match(regexp, buf):
        buf = re.sub(regexp, do_stuff, buf)
   else:
        buf += read(1024)
```

where `do_stuff` does the job and returns `''`, thus removing already processed stuff from the buffer

Comment: interesting... only issue I can think of is that it won't delete any area that doesn't match, which will slowly build up. Also the re.match call should be re.search I think

Comment: @ʞɔıu: I was assuming your regexp is "continuous" - if it's not, yes use search and if it matches remove the match and everything before it, like `buf = buf[match.end():]`